# sqlite is not working

Tags: sqlite, php

i came to know that, when we install php it automatically install sqlite. otherwise we need to enable it. is it correct?

i have installed php in my local server.when i execute the phpinfo it show sqlite enabled. still sqlite is not working.  below are the lines came under pdo_sqlite

**PECL Module version  1.0.1 $Id:** pdo_sqlite.c,v 1.10.2.6 2006/01/01 12:50:12 sniper Exp $
**SQLite Library**  3.3.6
apparat from this, anything i have to done. pls reply...

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"?

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by 'is not working'? Are the functions not there, are you getting any errors? If yes, what errors?

Comment: i am trying to connect the sqlite database using php, i am getting the error SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file

Comment: Then sqlite is probably working fine - its a permissions problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if you have read/write access to the database you are trying to open. I'm guessing this will solve the problem.